# Notification should stay

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have my application developed on `iOS 8` . I have implemented `push notification` in my application. In `iOS 8` clicking on `notification` automatically clears that particular notification. But my requirement is notification should stay until clear manually. Please give suggestion how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a system behavior. You can **not** prevent this to happen.
If you need something to be always visible from the notification center, consider to create a Notification Center Widget.

Comment: Thanx for the quick response. But these should get clear when user wants them to like earlier used to happen before ios8. User can manually clear all the notifications.

Comment: Even before iOS 8, opening an app by tapping on a notification would clear the notification.

Comment: i think in early versions we need to clear the `badge number` i.e `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to clear the tapped notification.